# Browse files on windows azure service

Tags: c#, azure-cloud-services

I'd like to browse the files on a cloud service I deployed through Visual Studio with some C# code, to compare file versions and modification dates between different cloud deployments.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The internals of the cloud service machine are generally (on purpose) obscured from you, because you shouldn't be relying on them.  Azure can, at any time, recycle/update/replace your instance with a fresh one whenever it decides it is important.

That being said, there are a few possibilities for this, but I would suggest coming at it from the other end, by making the service provide the information.

1) Set up a storage account, and have a background thread in your WorkerRole that dumps the information you are interested in to a table/blob on a scheduled basis.  Then write a simple C# client using Azure SDK to retrieve the records/listings from Azure Storage and analyze them locally. (BEST)

2) Expose an endpoint on your service that provides a simple WCF/TCP/REST API function you can call to get the information you want. (OK, but you need to secure/manage it or it will be a vulnerability)

3) Depending on how many instances you have, you could RDP into each of them with shares mapped and use a client on your local machine to pull the files from the shares (very hard to manage, very labor intensive, more secure than 2 since security/encryption is built into RDP)

The nice thing about #1 is that it very easily scales no matter how many services you have.  As long as you set each service and instance up with a unique identifier (look at RoleEnvironment class for this, you can get service name and instance ID to tag the results) you can have all of the data in one place.  And depending on how you want to browse, you can use tools like Azure Storage Explorer to just look at the data without even having to write C# analysis tools (depends again on the size and what you want to do with it).